# Table rendering issue: firefox 4, gecko

Tags: html, webkit, cross-browser, firefox4, gecko

In webkit browsers this page renders fine:

http://www.ryanhaywood.com/s/film.html

But in the updated firefox it is spaced horribly. I have messed around in firebug for days, I have no idea how to even fix this in firefox.

I apologize for the archaic solution (tables) deployed in aforementioned page

Can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks in advance
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had indicated creating layouts with tables is dated, I'd definitely agree.  Here's a  solution using `<div>`'s that should work in all browsers

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/hjgQm/

I've classed the films in a `left-orientation` and `right-orientation` alternating pattern of div's like so:

```
<div class="left-orientation">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x175/ff0" alt="Director's Reel" /></a>
    <p class="title">Director's Reel</p>
</div>
<div class="right-orientation">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x175/f00" alt="Nobody's Off The Hook" /></a>
    <p class="title">Nobody's Off The Hook</p>
</div>
```

and I used margins to control where the films show up within the parent div

```
#films div {width:46%;margin-top:-100px;}
#films .left-orientation {text-align:right;}
#films .right-orientation {margin-left:54%}
```

you can adjust the `#films div {margin-top:-100px;}` up or down to fit your desired height for offsetting the films